# ERROR: column "geom" does not exist Position: 66

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I am trying to create an sql view following this pgrouting workshop: https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.7/en/interactions/chapter-10.html

When copying:

```
    SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom) FROM (
        SELECT geom FROM wrk_fromAtoB('vehicle_net', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%
      ) ORDER BY seq) AS route
```

I get the error when clicking on refresh to show st_makeline that `column "geom" does not exist Position: 66`. I followed everything as shown in the workshop so I'm lost. I do have a column geom on my tables. I tried installing postgis-topology as mentioned in another post but that didn't help.

Comment: run `SELECT * FROM wrk_fromAtoB('vehicle_net', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%
      ) ORDER BY seq` to see what the columns are called

Comment: Some versions of this workshop have the function output geometry column named `geom` and others ([the latest](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/latest/en/basic/plpgsql_function.html#wrk-fromatob-function)) `route_geom`